# allowscriptaccess property ignored when object tag has no id (IE)

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, externalinterface

In IE, Flash ignores the allowscriptaccess=always property when the swf is embedded in an object tag that doesn't have an id attribute.  This is very easy to verify.  I have swfs that work completely fine in IE apart from not having the script access they should when the id attribute is missing.

Is there any way to code around this in AS2 or 3, assuming I have no control over whether the id attribute will be present or or not?  My aim is to capture window.location.href and navigator.userAgent through ExternalInterface.